# Tell Terraform to ignore Route53 resource in different workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I currently have 2 workspaces within Terraform, one for Prod and one for Dev.

In prod my Terraform code creates a Route53 entry and then add's a cert as a CNAME to the Route53 hosted zone and then attaches the cert to my load balancer.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "default" {
  domain_name = "www.test.uk"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "validation" {
  name = aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_name
  type = aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_type
  zone_id = "Z0725470IF9R8J77LPTU"
  records = [
    aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_value]
  ttl = "60"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "default" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.default.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [
    aws_route53_record.validation.fqdn,
  ]
}
```

When I switch my workspace to dev and run terraform apply it tries to creates this Route53 entry again and errors. Is there a way to tell Terraform to ignore this?

I tried adding a count of 0 but it gave me this error

> Error: Missing resource instance key
>
> on alb.tf line 12, in resource "aws_route53_record" "validation":
>   12:   type =
>   aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_type
>
> Because aws_acm_certificate.default has "count" set, its attributes
>   must be accessed on specific instances.
>
> For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
>       aws_acm_certificate.default[count.index]
>
> Error: Missing resource instance key
>
> on alb.tf line 15, in resource "aws_route53_record" "validation":
>   15:
>   aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[0].resource_record_value]
>
> Because aws_acm_certificate.default has "count" set, its attributes
>   must be accessed on specific instances.
>
> For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
>       aws_acm_certificate.default[count.index]

The best solution I've come up with is to comment out the Route53 stuff when I run terraform apply in the staging workspace, this obviously isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: That error message tells you how to fix the config to work with the `count` meta-argument. You can do that and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested below but I think you can use a conditional (based on your workspace name) and use count to create (or not create) the resources.

```
locals {
  create_me = terraform.workspace == "dev" ? 0 : 1
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "default" {
  count = local.create_me
  domain_name = "www.test.uk"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "validation" {
  count = local.create_me
  name = aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[count.index].resource_record_name
  type = aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[count.index].resource_record_type
  zone_id = "Z0725470IF9R8J77LPTU"
  records = [
    aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options[count.index].resource_record_value]
  ttl = "60"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "default" {
  count = local.create_me
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.default[count.index].arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [
    aws_route53_record.validation[count.index].fqdn,
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks good except that I'd suggest using `[count.index]` instead of `[0]` for the references between the resources, so that Terraform will understand that the intention is to correlate these together by count index, otherwise validation will tend to conservatively report that there is no index zero when `count = 0`.

Comment: Oh that's a good point, copypasta'd from the main post and didn't consider it- I'll update.